# Is there a way to use Cassandra to detect the topology of the network?

Tags: cassandra, distributed-computing

It's my understanding that Cassandra's snitch protocol enables all nodes to maintain a picture of the network topology (i.e., reachability) for all nodes in the cluster. The application I'm working on also needs to know the state of the network topology of the nodes on which Cassandra is running. Is the topological information that is computed in Cassandra exposed in any way via an API, or do I have to re-create this topology myself? I'd prefer not to have to re-invent the wheel to support this functionality. What's my best option for achieving this?

Comment: Just a guess - what if you wrote a custom snitch that delegates to an existing snitch. The custom snitch could expose the topology by a means of your choice. JMX perhaps.

Comment: "Cassandra exposed in any way via an API" Cassandra is open source, so you could snoop around in the source code for the internal API it uses. But that internal API is not guaranteed to be stable, so your code might cease to work after an upgrade.